# javascript alerts undefined after text is set with innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I know this problem seems trivial, but it's got me stumped. I'm storing a value using Javascript's `innerHTML` property and then retrieving it with `value`. However, when I alert the value the popup box reads `undefined` even though the text appears in the dom.

```js
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    document.getElementById("storeValue").innerHTML="alertme";
     var getvalu = document.getElementById("storeValue").value;
     alert(getvalu);
    });
```

```html
<div id="storeValue"></div>
```

Comment: Div's don't have values. To retrieve the content use the same attribute that you set (i.e. `document.getElementById("storeValue").innerHTML`)

Comment: Have you checked the docs for what the `value` method is supposed to return? It's not what you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is because there is no property value for div. use `innerHTML` again or you can also use `.textContent`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="storeValue"></div>
</html>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
document.getElementById("storeValue").innerHTML="alertme";
var getvalu = document.getElementById("storeValue").innerHTML;
alert(getvalu);
}); 

</script>
```